# Raspberry Pi 6.1.0 OS Cron Job Configuration Issue: Running Twice on Different Dates

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

I'm facing an unexpected behavior with cron job configuration on my Raspberry Pi running OS version 6.1.0. When setting up a one-time cron job with specific parameters for both the day of the week and the day of the month, it appears that the day of the week parameter is overriding the day of the month.

For clarity, I configured a cron job using the following settings: `06 21 2 3 6`, intending for it to execute at *21:06 on the 2nd of March, a Saturday*. However, I observed that the job ran not only on the *2nd* of March but also on the *9th* of March, which is still a Saturday.

Has anyone else encountered this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

man 5 crontab wrote:

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields
> — day of month, and day of week.   If both  fields  are  restricted
> (ie, aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the
> current time.  For example, ``30 4 1,15 * 5'' would cause a command to
> be run at 4:30 am on the 1st and 15th of each month, plus  every
> Friday.